# If I add an SSD to a non-retina MBP 13" will weight drop to 3.5 lbs

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd, display

I'm shopping for a new computer for university, and I'm considering the MBP 13". I don't do graphic intensive work, so I do not need the retina display. It's not worth the extra cash. However, because I'm constantly carrying around my computer and turning it on and off, I want an ultrabook: something light and fast to boot. I'm thinking of buying the 13" non-retina MBP, but selecting the 256 mb SSD option instead of the HD option. If I do that, of course, apple will drop the HD and optical drive from the machine. Will that get the weight down to 3.57 lbs? If so, it might be a cost effective way for me to get the machine I'm looking for.

Thanks.

Comment: Get the Ultralight MacBook Air, with 8 hours of battery life.

Comment: Why not go for the top of range macair?   You will have a lighter computer and will not have to pay the premium for the SSD.   Mac Airs have been updated in June 2013 non-Retina Macbook Pro last update last year as far as I can remember...   If you do not need the added CPU power of the Pro go Air.   Great battery life and light.

Comment: I travel a lot, and after some mistakes in my life (buying the wrong laptops), I figured out that the weight is the most important, followed by battery life. I have the MBA and I love it. It has performances that i did not exceed yet, it is fast. I carry one cable with me HDMI, to hook up to large TV when watching movies :).

Comment: base weight of 13 inc MBP is 4.5 pounds... does not have optical drive so HD to SSD replacement is not going to save 1 pound..  MacAir 13 inch base weight 2.96 pounds

Answer (score 1):

If you upgrade the 13" non-retina MBP to a 256 GB SSD, that only saves you $100 vs. a retina MBP with the same 256 GB SSD ($1599 vs. $1699).

Furthermore, the non-retina MBP will still have the optical drive no matter what (you can't configure it without one). So the only difference in weight will be the difference between the SSD and traditional HDD, whatever that is (I suspect not much, since Apple's own tech specs only say "actual weight varies by configuration").

The 13" MacBook Air is a much better fit for what you're looking for: lower price ($1299), much lower weight (2.96 lbs).